# python dictionary do not print if there is no value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have written a short script to print some info based on information in a CSV file.

What I need to be able to do is to make the print function not print if there is no value for the key, or if there is a default value such as 'n/a'.

Or it may be that if there is a default or empty cell in the CSV, that it doesn't get added to the dictionary? Not sure what is the best option.

```
import csv

with open('lhcdes.csv', 'rb') as testcsv:
    myfile = csv.DictReader(testcsv)
    for row in myfile:
    print 'Key1 %s' %  row.get('Key1') + '\n' + 'and ' + 'Key2:%s ' % row.get('Key2') + 'Key3:%s ' % row.get('Key3:')
```

the CSV Format is as follow:

```
Key1,Key2,Key3,Key4,Key5,Key6
Gi0/3/0/1.1838,CustA,EU1,AN-12345,TAL12345,Host1_London
Gi0/3/0/1.2072,CustB,EU2,AN-12346,TAL12346,Host2_Manchester
Gi0/3/0/2.3761,CustB,EU3,AN-12347,TAL12347,Not Found
Gi0/3/0/3.3573,CustC,EU7,AN-12348,TAL12348,Host5_Swansea
Gi0/3/0/3.3702,CustD,EU5,AN-12349,N/A,Host4_Glasgow
Gi0/3/0/3.3917,CustB,EU6,AN-12350,TAL12350,Not Found
Gi0/3/0/3.3918,CustA,EU2,AN-12351,TAL12351,N/A
Gi0/3/0/3.3919,CustE,EU9,AN-12352,Not Found,Not Found
Gi0/3/0/3.3923,CustE,EU9,AN-12353,TAL12353,N/A
Gi0/3/0/4.512,CustC,EU8,AN-12354,TAL12354,Not Found
```

The output should look like

```
interface Gi0/3/0/1.1838
Client:CustA EU:EU1 IR:AN-12345 CR:TAL12345 R:Host1_London
interface Gi0/3/0/1.2072
Client:CustB EU:EU2 IR:AN-12346 CR:TAL12346 R:Host2_Manchester


Where info is absent or n/a

interface Gi0/3/0/3.3919
Client:CustE EU:EU9 IR:AN-12352
```

Comment: And what output are your trying to get for the CSV?

Comment: added that too now

Comment: I am wondering whether I would be better of creating a new string object and then using a regex to remove stuff that contains 'none'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test the contents of `Key5` and `Key6` for a `missing` value and then format your output accordingly:

```
import csv

missing = ['Not Found', None, 'N/A', '']

with open('lhcdes.csv', 'rb') as testcsv:
    myfile = csv.DictReader(testcsv)

    for row in myfile:
        if row['Key5'] in missing or row['Key6'] in missing:
            print 'interface {}\nClient: {} {} IR:{}'.format(
                row['Key1'], row['Key2'], row['Key3'], row['Key4'])
        else:
            print 'interface {}\nClient: {} {} IR:{} CR:{} R:{}'.format(
                row['Key1'], row['Key2'], row['Key3'], row['Key4'], row['Key5'], row['Key6'])
```

The script would display the following output:

```
interface Gi0/3/0/1.1838
Client: CustA EU1 IR:AN-12345 CR:TAL12345 R:Host1_London
interface Gi0/3/0/1.2072
Client: CustB EU2 IR:AN-12346 CR:TAL12346 R:Host2_Manchester
interface Gi0/3/0/2.3761
Client: CustB EU3 IR:AN-12347
interface Gi0/3/0/3.3573
Client: CustC EU7 IR:AN-12348 CR:TAL12348 R:Host5_Swansea
interface Gi0/3/0/3.3702
Client: CustD EU5 IR:AN-12349
interface Gi0/3/0/3.3917
Client: CustB EU6 IR:AN-12350
interface Gi0/3/0/3.3918
Client: CustA EU2 IR:AN-12351
interface Gi0/3/0/3.3919
Client: CustE EU9 IR:AN-12352
interface Gi0/3/0/3.3923
Client: CustE EU9 IR:AN-12353
interface Gi0/3/0/4.512
Client: CustC EU8 IR:AN-12354
```

Comment: Thanks,  I have tested the solution provided by Arne Recknagel above and it works in the sense that it won't print entry if it matches the key value but I need the print format to be a specific way. If you look at my first post the print statement has a newline and 'and ' in it.

Comment: And how would that be formatted if the `Key1` was missing?

Comment: Key1 will always be present, so would Key 2-3 but then there are other keys that are optional or only relevant to certain items.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to include a full example showing the CSV input and your expected output for it.

Comment: btw I am gettin an error when trying the above code:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "readcsv.py", line 15, in <module>
       values = ['{}: {}'.format(key, row[key]) for key in keys if key in row]
    NameError: name 'keys' is not defined

Comment: `keys` is the first line of the script after the import. Did you copy it?

Comment: That makes it much clearer, I have updated the script to hopefully work correctly.

Comment: Thanks it works and I'm not looking into the format command. Only been using python for a few weeks.

The above code works but I realised I would ideally need all the info otherwise any anomalies thrown up will break it and I can't really account for missing information in every field as the real data is likely to be hundreds of lines with various info missing.

So I need to make sure we have as much info as possible.

Comment: One approach would be to replace all missing fields with a consistent entry e.g. `MISSING`. This could be done by adding `row = {k : 'MISSING' if v in missing else v for k, v in row.items()}` before the `if row...`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to print the keys in a loop, given a condition:

```
import csv

with open('lhcdes.csv', 'rb') as testcsv:
    myfile = csv.DictReader(testcsv)
    keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']              # a list of all keys you want to print
    default_value = 'n/a'                        # the default value you want to skip
    for row in myfile:
        for key in keys:
            value = row.get(key, default_value)  # get the value at 'key', or the
                                                 # default value if 'key' was not found 
            if value == default_value:
                continue                         # skip to the next item in the 'keys' 
                                                 # list
            print("{} {}".format(key, value))    # use .format over '%' syntax
```

This way, you skip any entries where there was either not value or whatever your default is.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to give this a go and report back. Is there a way so that if the cell is empty that it will also skip it?

Comment: This worked but I need to print the data in a specific format. essentially I need something in the print statement that will say print x if there is a value but don't print it if there isn't a null value or it is empty